# Screen stays black after memory upgrade?

Tags: memory, upgrade, acer-aspire, black-screen-of-death, ddr

I have 4GB memory from my **`HP Folio 13 1020us`**, labelled:

> **4GB 2Rx8 PC3-12800S-11-11-F3**

I want to use it to replace the memory in my **`ACER E1-510`**. It's current memory is labelled:

> **2GB 1Rx8 PC3L-12800S-11**

Apparently the Acer can take up to 4GB, however when I install it**the screen stays black** when I power it on. (No *Acer* logo, etc.)

***Am I missing something?***

---

More Info:

[image]

According to [CRUCIAL.COM](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP-Compaq/hp-folio-13-1020us) the **HP** could take:

> ```
> 4GB DDR3L-1866 SODIMM CT51264BF186DJ   (Configuration ID: CT3431127)
> DDR3 PC3-14900 • CL=13 • UNBUFFERED • NON-ECC • DDR3-1866 • 1.35V •
> ```

According to [CRUCIAL.COM](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-e1-510-2683) the **ACER** could take:

> ```
> 4GB DDR3L-1600 SODIMM CT51264BF160B    (Configuration ID: CT5346972)
> DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • UNBUFFERED • NON-ECC • DDR3-1600 • 1.35V •
> ```

Comment: The Acer may support up to 4GB but as 2*2GB ONLY, like almost all of similar computers.